# Drives in Dell MD3000i hot-swappable

Tags: dell

Can we install new 2 hard drives in Dell PowerVault MD3000i (into the second half which is empty) without powering down the enclosure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/storage/pvaul_md3000i/pd.aspx?refid=pvaul_md3000i&cs=555&s=biz says you can.

Hard Drives
Controller Module:
Up to fifteen (15) 3.5-inch SAS or SATA **hot-pluggable** hard drives, at speeds of 5.4K, 7.2K, 10K or 15K

Expansion Module:
Two expansion modules each holding up to fifteen (15) 3.5-inch SAS or SATA **hot-pluggable** hard drives, at speeds of 5.4K, 7.2K, 10K or 15K

Comment: Thank you. I saw that page but still was not sure how it behaves in reality.

Answer (score 1):

To give you some real world data - I just added 5 new drives to two MD3000i's today with no issues. Works just as expected and when you open up the MD3000i Manager application it will guide you through your options - create a new Volume\expand existing ones and then assign any new volumes to groups for presentation.